# How to pass parameters in onclick function of generated html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

In my controller code contain html code in appened form.When i pass the parameters  to the onclick function, I didn't get the parameters in the corresponding function.

**controller**

```
         foreach ($cart as $item){ 
          $row_id = $item['rowid'];
          //    $count++;
            $output.='
            <tr>
               <td>'.$item['name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$item['price'].'</td>
               <td>'.$item['qty'].'</td>
               <td>'.number_format($item['subtotal'],2).'</td>
               <td> <a href="" onclick="remove("'.$row_id.'")" class="item-remove"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i></a></td>
            </tr>

            ';

     }
```

**script**

```
   function remove(row_id)
    {

        alert(row_id);
    }
```

Onclick function remove(), alert is not working

Comment: why you are not using jquery..?

Comment: Try changing `remove("'.$row_id.'")` to `remove('.$row_id.')`, that should work.

Comment: its not working

Comment: if you use remove(2) it works..?

Comment: @DharmendraSingh You've just settled a bet :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your old code is producing

```
<td> <a href="" onclick="remove("1")" class="item-remove"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i></a></td>
```

which is an incorrect HTML

just replace this

```
onclick="remove("'.$row_id.'")"
```

with this

```
onclick="remove(\''.$row_id.'\')"
```

see a demo : https://eval.in/830107

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="remove("'.$row_id.'")"
```

Will result in:

```
onclick="remove("123")"
```

See where its going wrong? Onclick now contains only the portion remove(, because than a double quote termintes the onclick content.